# What is difference between "string" and string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was reading *you dont know js* (Up and going) and i stumbled across this piece of line

> The return value from the typeof operator is always one of six (seven
>   as of ES6!) string values. That is, `typeof "abc"` returns `"string"`, not
>   `string`.

I am unable to understand difference between `"string"` and `string`.
Whenever i check any typeof for a string value,
the value is `"string"`.

Can I get help in understanding this

Comment: What the author wanted to say is: *That is, `typeof "abc"` returns the type  `"string"`, (as string, since the quotes, not as object `string`).*  ...If you ask me, how I'd explain this, for beginners, is: *`typeof` returns a string representing the type: `typeof "foo"` returns `"string"`, `typeof 5` returns `"number"` etc.* - ironically the name of the book...

Comment: Try this for yourself `typeof true`. You'll see `"boolean"`. The author meant to say that the keyword `typeof` always returns the type wrapped in quotation marks (as a string). Therefore you can do things like `if (typeof input === 'string')`

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` operator always returns a string type. In this instance, it just so happens that the type you're checking *is* a string. How do you represent the type `string` as a string itself? Wrap it in quotes.